# How to make horizontal line span entire width of overflow: scroll element?

Tags: html, css

I have a "timeline" component and I want to put a horizontal line accross it:

```css
.container {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}

.timeline-box {
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.timeline-strip {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    position: relative;
}

.timeline-strip:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
}

.point {
    margin: 0 40px;
    align-self:center;
}
.point:before {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="timeline-box">
      <div class="timeline-strip">

        <div class="point">1</div>
        <div class="point">2</div>
        <div class="point">3</div>
        <div class="point">4</div>
        <div class="point">5</div>
        <div class="point">6</div>
        <div class="point">7</div>
        <div class="point">8</div>
        <div class="point">9</div>
        <div class="point">10</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, the horizontal line only has a width of the visible width - When I scroll the component the horizontal line stops.
If I set `.timeline-strip` to `display: inline-flex`, then the horizontal line goes all the way but now the timeline doesn't fit into the container. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `overflow-x: scroll;` to the timeline-box and make the timeline-strip `display:inline-flex;`

```css
.container {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;

}

.timeline-box {
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    overflow-x: scroll; 
}

.timeline-strip {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
}

.timeline-strip:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
}

.point {
    margin: 0 40px;
    align-self:center;
}
.point:before {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="timeline-box">
      <div class="timeline-strip">

        <div class="point">1</div>
        <div class="point">2</div>
        <div class="point">3</div>
        <div class="point">4</div>
        <div class="point">5</div>
        <div class="point">6</div>
        <div class="point">7</div>
        <div class="point">8</div>
        <div class="point">9</div>
        <div class="point">10</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Explanation:

CSS layout is all about the interaction between container boxes and their content boxes.

So here, we have the `timeline-strip::before` content box which has width 100%. That's 100% the width of its container box generated by the `timeline-strip` box. When it's `display:flex` and no explicit width is set, its width follows the block-level layout rules and so is determined by its container box which is the timeline-box.

But the desired width for the `timeline-strip` box is the width of its contents. The contents are being laid out using flexbox rules, so there's only two choices for the display property: `flex` and `inline-flex`. Inline-flex has the desired behaviour, it's as wide as its contents. It can also be achieved with `flex`, by giving it a `width:fit-content` (and currently for Firefox, `width:-moz-fit-content`)

Now, because the `timeline-strip` box is as wide as its contents, and its container `timeline-box` box has a width limited by the window size, the `timeline-strip` box can be wider than its container box. The part of content that doesn't fit in its container box is called "overflow". It's the `overflow` setting on the container element that determines how that overflow is handled. In this case, the desired behaviour is to be able to scroll the content within the container box so to do that, the container `timeline-box` element is given the setting `overflow-x: scroll;` or `overflow-x: auto`;

Comment: Sweet, thank you. Can you explain why it is like this? I am finding it hard to understand CSS

Comment: @asker - I've tried to provide some explanation of what's going on. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `position: fixed` in `.timeline-strip:before {` and adjust `top: 170px;` and the `width: 27vw`.

I know this is a cluncy solution but this is what i would have done.

Changed CSS:

```
.timeline-strip:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 170px;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  width: 27vw;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Sorry but that's all I got. Maybe I was able to still help you out.